# Can I call one function that not declared in the interface but implemented in the contract?

Tags: solidity

**Example:**

```
interface IA {
    function a1(uint256) public returns();
}
```

```
import "./IA.sol";

contract A is IA {
    function a1(uint256 _a1) public returns() {
        _a = 1;
    }

    function a2(uint256 _a2) public returns() {
        _a2 = 2;
    }
}
```

```
import "./IA.sol";

contract B {
    IA a;
    function b(address _aAddress, uint256 _a2) public returns(uint256) {
        a = IA(_aAddress);
        a.a2(_a2);
        return _a2;
    }
}
```

**Question:**

When I try to interact with a contract by using `interface(contractAddress)`, can I call one function that not declared in the interface but implemented in the contract?

For example, Can I call the `a2()` of contract `A` in the contract `B` in this way?

Answer (score 2):

You have at least two options:

1. Write your own interface which inherits from the `IA` and adds the missing functionality. This is by far the nicest approach
2. Use something like `call` or `delegateCall` to call functionality in another contract without direct reference to the function. So basically you craft the call to the other function by hand. You can find more info with examples here: https://medium.com/coinmonks/delegatecall-calling-another-contract-function-in-solidity-b579f804178c